# How can I use rsync filters properly?

Tags: linux, rsync, filter

I'm having trouble in getting rsync to respect my `.rsync-filter` files; which, I guess, it is due to me not properly understanding how they work.

Basically, I have made a filter inside my `$HOME` folder and a file, with the same name but with different contents, inside a different dir which I'd like to sync. The filter file inside my home dir seems to (somewhat) work, but the other one does not seem to work properly.

This is the command `rsync -auzvrR --no-l --no-H --filter='dir-merge /.rsync-filter' --exclude='venvs' --exclude='from_git' $HOME /mnt/backups/obk/ --dry-run > $HOME/Documents/rsync_results/home.txt` and this is the filter file inside my home dir:

```
# rsync filter for /home dir

+ /[Dd]ocuments
+ /[Dd]ocuments/***
+ /[Dd]ownloads
+ /[Dd]ownloads/***
+ /[Mm]usic
+ /[Mm]usic/**
+ /[Pp]ictures
+ /[Pp]ictures/***
+ /[Vv]ideos
+ /[Vv]ideos/***
+ /.anacron
+ /.anacron/***
+ /.bash_aliases
+ /.bashrc
+ /.blerc
- *
```

This is the command `rsync -auzvvrR --no-l --no-H --filter='dir-merge /.rsync-filter' $HOME/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/data/Steam Music/ --dry-run > $HOME/Documents/rsync_results/steam.txt` and the one inside my Steam directory (I've tried putting the filter file in different directories, but to no avail):

```
+ /userdata
+ /userdata/***
+ /home/[REDACTED]/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/steamapps/common
+ /home/[REDACTED]/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/steamapps/common/***
```

As you can see I've tried with both full and relative paths, but it makes no difference.

This is the output of `tree`:

```
/home/[REDACTED]/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam
├── cache -> .cache
├── config -> .config
├── data -> .local/share
├── Music
└── Pictures
```

How can I make a single `.rsync-filter` file in my home dir and make `rsync` only sync the files and folders I've specified inside of said file? Also, is it possible to include strings of file and/or folder names to exclude?

---

**EDIT:** The suggestion mentioned in the comments by Freddy works. But I'd like to exclude some of the folders in one of the subdirs.

This is the filter:

```
# rsync -auvzR --no-l --no-H --filter='dir-merge .rsync-filter' /home/[REDACTED]/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/data/Steam --dry-run
+ /steamapps
+ /steamapps/common/***
+ /userdata
+ /userdata/***
### These dirs do not get excluded
- /steamapps/common/Proton - Experimental
- /steamapps/common/Proton EasyAntiCheat Runtime
- /steamapps/common/Steam.dll             # file
- /steamapps/common/Steam Controller Configs
- /steamapps/common/SteamLinuxRuntime_soldier
- /steamapps/common/Steamworks Shared
###
- *
```

Comment: I use a  * as first char so Documents are all picked up. Although really only in /home/$USER/Documents. Some examples of exclude, but include would be similar: http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997

Comment: @oldfred That kinda works, but it'd make my life a whole lot easier if I could exclude everything *except* folders/files that match a certain pattern. Particularly folders which have a lot of subfolders.

Comment: @Freddy The whole first part of the string is the src/ while Music/ is the dest/. Sorry if this was confusing, but I'm just testing atm so I needed a clean dir to copy to.

Comment: Yes, my bad. If you wanted to include `steamapps/common/` and its content, add `- *` analog to your first filter to the end of the file and include `+ /steamapps` and `+ /steamapps/common/***`. Put the filter into the `Steam` source dir. Look at the output of `-v --dry-run` without filter and prefix the paths you want with a `+ /` (absolute to the source dir) and make sure you include all parent dirs up to the source dir. Use `-vv` / `-vvv` to get verbose output of the filters.

Comment: @Freddy The filter seems to work now. Thanks :) How can I exclude dirs and/or files using the same filter? Please see my updated post.

Comment: Works for me if you move the excluded dirs to the top of the file (before `+ /steamapps/common/***`) and remove the `# file` comment. I'd only add a `/` to each directory to make it easier to read.